# In NiFi, how can time-zones be handled when transferring data between DB's where the time-zone differs between the source and destination DB servers?

Tags: java, apache-nifi

We are attempting to copy data from an Oracle database, which operates on the CEST time zone, to a PostgreSQL database, which operates on the UST time zone. Therefore, when copying data from Oracle to PostgreSQL, the DATE column data should not be directly transferred but rather adjusted to the UST time zone before being inserted into PostgreSQL.

Approach.1:
We tried using **ExecuteSql** processor (which uses **AvroWriter** by default) to extract data and **PutDatabaseRecord** processor with **AvroReader** to load data to postgres. In this approach data was getting copied as-is.

Approach.2:
We tried using **ExecuteSqlRecord** processor with **JsonRecordSetWriter** and **PutDatabaseRecord** processor with **JsonTreeReader**, In this approach we are able to configure the format to be considered for date, time & timestamp data types. But, we didn't found any configuration where we can set the time-zone needed to be used.

JsonRecordSetWriter configuration:
[image: JsonRecordSetWriter configuration]

JsonTreeReader confiuration:
[image: JsonTreeReader confiuration]

What exaclty we are expecting is,
if in Source one of the DATE column value is : `2023-07-12 13:47:31` (UST)

In Target, it should be loaded as : `2023-07-12 11:47:31` (CEST)

Could someone please suggest if achieving this in NiFi is possible and if so, how? Alternatively, are there any workarounds that can be implemented at the database level? Or it can be some property of JVM or nifi?